# How to set default time manually?

Tags: datetime

I am using calender module and going to set up a site. The problem is that the default time on the site can not be set correctly through admin/settings/date-time to reflect the local time.

The values in the drop-down menu turn out to be either half an hour late or early. Also, for the reason of backup synchronisations I can not tweak the server's time.  So I am wondering if there a way to cope with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: where are you?  what timezone are you trying to set?

Comment: The server is in the US East but the time zone that I am going to fix is GMT+3.5

Comment: GMT+3.5 is usually Asia/Teheran. However, Iran switched to daylight savings time on March 21, 2012, so it is now GMT+4.5. At the moment, no city uses GMT+3.5.